# How to apply aspect dynamically?

Tags: c#, metaprogramming, postsharp

I have this clas:

```
[NotifyPropertyChangedAspect] // my own aspect implementation...
class Foo {
    [OnSetAspect("OnSetExamplaryProperty")] // my own aspect implementation as well...
    public int ExamplaryProperty { get; set; }
    void OnSetExamplaryProperty() { /* do stuff... */ }

    public bool Condition { get; set; }

    [DependsOnAspect("Condition")]
    public bool Dependent { get; set; }
}
```

Whenever `Condition` changes, I want to fire the `PropertyChanged` with `PropertyName == "Dependent"` as well. I know I can do it vice versa (apply the aspect on `Condition` with its dependent properties, or just add a `PropertyChanged` handler in the constructor), but I want it this way :-)

So here are the possible solutions I could think of:

1. Somehow inject my own `OnSetAspect` during compilation (override `CompileTimeInitialize`? using `Emit`?)
2. Somehow inject my own `OnSetAspect` during runtime (again, how?)
3. Apply my own `OnSetAspect` using `IAspectProvider` (I'm guessing here... not really sure about feasibility and/or implementation simplicity)

So how do I fill up my `DependsOnAspect` class body to achieve my goal?

```
[Serializable]
public class DependsOnAspect : LocationInterceptionAspect {
    /* what goes here? */
}
```

What's the simplest solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you should intercept `set_Condition` and fire the `PropertyChanged` event here. So the `DependsOnAspect` doesn't really need to be an aspect (you do not need to transform Dependent because it has the attribute on it property) - just a regular attribute.

The outline would be: `NotifyPropertyChangedAspect` will provide `OnMethodBoundaryAspect`s (it will implement `IAspectProvider`) to all property setters and analyze all properties for `[DependsOn]` attributes (at build time). In runtime each property setter aspect will fire `PropertyChangedEvent` for all properties that had `[DependsOn]` attribute pointing to the particular property.

```
public class DependsOnAttribute : Attribute { ... }

[PSerializable]
[IntroduceInterface(typeof(INotifyPropertyChanged))]
public class NotifyPropertyChangedAspect : InstanceLevelAspect, IAspectProvider, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    IEnumerable<AspectInstance> IAspectProvider.ProvideAspects(object targetElement)
    {
        // targetElement is Type, go through it's properties and provide SetterInterceptionAspect to them
    }

    public override void CompileTimeInitialize( Type type, AspectInfo aspectInfo )
    {
        // scan for [DependsOn] here
    }

    [PSerializable]
    public class SetterInterceptionAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
    {
        // ...
        public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
        {
            // fire PropertyChanged event here
        }
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

You would need to tinker with it a little bit, but I hope that this will be usable as an outline.

Comment: It looks promising, just one question - how do I exclude certain properties? I can't apply `[NotifyPropertyChangedAspect(AttributeExclude = true)]` to properties. Do I have to create another attribute for that?

Comment: @Tal Yes, you would need another attribute and in the ProvideAspects method you are going to filter properties based on presence of that attribute. Note that NotifyPropertyChangedAspect is applied only on type, so the exclude on property does not make any sense because the aspect was not on that property in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. And why do I need `CompileTimeInitialize`? I do all the work in `ProvideAspects`. I can emit an error there, if I need.. no?

Comment: And another thing - I need to fire `PropertyChanged` in run-time, how do I pass the dependencies data?

Comment: @Tal You can introduce a special interface, that would allow you to access this information from the inner aspect. Something like `(args.Instance as IDependencyDataProvider).Dependencies`. the other way is to use Advices instead of the inner aspect and access it directly, but that requires PostSharp Pro. Anyway, have you given Model Pattern library a try?

Comment: As a sidenote - you would also need to deal with the fact that the whole data will be copied per-instance. That can be solved by TypeLevelAspect containing the analyzed data on top of that or by implementing `ISerializationCallback`.